Electron + Vuetify cannot trigger touch keyboard / tabtip.exe on kiosk touch screen
I have an application built using ElectronForge and Vuetify
This is a fullscreen application for kiosks.
The problem is that when it is installed on the kiosk, the touch keyboard does not appear when focusing on the input.
I thought it was because I was using the text field component from Vuetify, but after replacing it with standard html input, the touch keyboard still doesn't work
This application also redirects to an external url. in this external url the touch keyboard also doesn't work
I can add KioskBoard to the components in the project, but for pages loaded from external urls, I can't add a KioskBoard
How do I solve this?
Kiosk using Windows 10
Electronforge version 7.2.0
Vuetify version 3.7.4
